# "Permutation of a set" vs "permutation of a Rubik's cube": are these uses of "permutation" equivalent?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, rubiks-cube

So my book defines a permutation as follows : *"By a permutation of  a  set A  we  mean  a bijective  function  from A to A,  that  is,  a  one-to-one correspondence between A and itself."*

This is perfectly clear to me.

However, when talking about objects like the [Rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube). People refer to the state of the Rubik's cube as a *"permutation of the cube"*.

Now my question is:

> Are these definitions distinct? i.e., is "permutation" a homonym with two meanings, or are these definitions somehow equivalent?

Comment: The (standard) Rubik's cube consists of 54 faces.  The faces are a set which may be permuted by a rotation of a section of the cube.  Any particular state of the cube can be seen as the image of a solved cube after a number of rotations, i.e. the image of the solved cube after the action of a bijective function from the set of faces to itself.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: That sounds like a better answer than the currently posted one. (For bonus points it could note that a cube with a side length of more than three has some faces that have the same color, yet can be interchanged by legal moves, such that some legal and nontrivial permutations make no visible difference on a solved cube, and therefore permutations _cannot_ be identified with states on larger cubes).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I considered expanding my comment into an answer, but I honestly exhausted just about everything that I know about groups in that comment.  I would be more than happy for someone more qualified than myself to take my comment and run with it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm As far as I can tell, all you're saying is that the permutations acting on a labeled+oriented cube is different from the permutations acting on an unlabeled cube.  If so, sure.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: The permutations that *act on* a (4×4×4 or larger) cube are real permutations, but the _states_ of the cube cannot be identified with those permutations.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And my point is that this depends on how you define "states" of the cube.  If you label and orient the cubes, then the resulting states are in a one-to-one correspondence with the group of permutations acting on the cube.  They only won't be if you force the definition of "states" to be those of an unlabeled cube.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, it does depend on the definition of a "state". And Henning is surely aware of that. Even on a 3x3x3 there are subtleties. For some purposes the orientations of the center faces plays a role (IIRC this is often called a *supercube*). There people draw arrows on the stickers so that in a solved state the arrows on a single face all line up, There are sequences of moves that leave the non-arrowed visual appearance of a cube in tact, but rotate the arrows on the center stickers.

Comment: The same phenomenon plays a role in a wonderful gift I got from a godchild of mine: a 3x3x3 cube, all the stickers black, but with a white digit $1,\ldots,9$  on it. In a solved state the stickers must obey the rules of a sudoku, and the orientations of the digits on every face must also match.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Now, that's something I didn't actually know: that orientation plays a nontrivial role in the centers of a 3x3x3 cube - I was under the mistaken impression that this wasn't so, since their relative positions cannot change.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Knowing that, I do need to change my answer some.

Comment: @BrianMoehring  A group theoretic difference is that on a 3x3x3 cube the subgroup of permutations that fixes the visual appearance of the cube is a normal subgroup of all the (legal) permutations of the supercube. One of Henning's points can be rephrased by saying that on a 4x4x4 this is no longer true. For example, a move sequence with the effect that it permutes three pieces in the middle of a single face does leave the visual appearance of a solved state in tact, but will change the appearance of many non-solved states. Therefore that subgroup is not normal inside the bigger group.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Right -- so if instead of permutations of _faces_ we consider permutations of _all points on the exterior of the cube_ (minus the face boundaries), then we can't identify the visual states of a (non-super) 3×3×3 with permutations anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The answer ultimately depends on what you mean by "the state of the Rubik's cube."  I'll consider two cases, the first initially being more complicated, but for which the answer is easier, and the second being simpler, but with a more complicated answer.

**Case 1:** Take a solved rubik's cube (or similar, this will work for any size cube) and label each square with a distinct label and an orientation.  For instance, on a 3x3x3 cube, you can label each square on a given side with the numbers 1-9 and underline each number.  Finally, decide on an orientation for the colors of the solved cube (e.g. choose an orientation for the front, top, right corner).  In this case, we take the numbers and their orientations, as well as the orientation of our chosen corner, into account to define each state.

**Case 2:** Don't label the rubik's cube in any way.

Now apply a sequence of moves to the cube, writing down each as you go (e.g. I've seen people write "BBLRUDDDU..." for a 3x3x3, not sure what the notation is for larger cubes).  Each rotation itself is a permutation which we allow to act on the cube to yield a state of the cube, so the sequence of rotations is also a permutation.  In this way, we can define the permutations acting on the cube as any of the permutations you can get by a sequence of rotations.

As it was defined in Case 1, the resulting state of the cube can actually be identified by the product of rotations that reached that state from the "solved" state.  In this case, we can say that the given state of the cube represents the permutation we applied to the cube.  This allows us, for instance, to define a given state as a permutation you can then apply to any other state of the cube.

As it was defined in Case 2, the resulting state of the cube can come from many different permutations.  In fact, there are some permutations that would bring us back to a solved cube but would change an unsolved cube, so there's really no hope in identifying "permutations of a cube" with the underlying permutation applied to the cube.

---

That is, if you define "state," and therefore "permutation of the cube" using the definition given in case 1, then the permutations acting on the cube are in a natural correspondence with the states of the cube, so we can identify them.

On the other hand, if you define "state" as in case 2, then the "permutations of the cube" are just the results of a given set of permutations *acting* on the cube. In general, however, there is no nice way to try to choose a permutation that the given state represents, so we have to conclude that defining "permutation of the cube" as the given state is a little abuse of notation.

---

*A final note specific to the unlabeled 3x3x3 cube:* it was pointed out to me that the orientation of the center cubes on each side can differ between two solved cubes (which is the reason I had to rewrite my original answer).  However, such a permutation, applied to an unlabeled cube, can never result in a different unlabeled state, so even though we still cannot identify the unlabeled state of the cube with the permutation itself, we *can* reasonably identify the state of the cube with an *equivalence class of permutations*.  It still is a little bit of an abuse of notation to identify the state as a permutation, but this shows that it's at least a harmless abuse of notation.